# Mosquitto with MQTT.js Allowed Protocols

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto broker and I can connect to it using `mqtt://`, `mqtts://`, `ws://` and `wss://` protocols. Now is there a way to use `ssl://` as protocol? I am using MQTT.js library.
I have seen two examples of this using Paho [here](https://openest.io/en/2020/01/03/mqtts-how-to-use-mqtt-with-tls/) and [here](https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-edge-connect/docs/mqtt-over-tls-ssl)

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail? And what do you think the difference is between `mqtts://` and `ssl://`?

Answer (score 1):

From the MQTT.js [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttconnecturl-options):

> The URL can be on the following protocols: 'mqtt', 'mqtts', 'tcp',
> 'tls', 'ws', 'wss', 'wxs', 'alis'. The URL can also be an object as
> returned by URL.parse(), in that case the two objects are merged, i.e.
> you can pass a single object with both the URL and the connect
> options.

`ssl://` is a legacy hold over from early IBM MQTT client libraries and probably should be deprecated in favour of `mqtts://` they both mean the same thing, connect using Native MQTT over a TLS encrypted link.

If you want to support this URL style with a NodeJS client then I suggest you write a short bit of code to check if the input starts with `ssl://` and replace it with `mqtts://`

Comment: I'm trying to find any description of what `wxs` protocol is, and I can't.  Same with `alis`.  I'm also not sure what the difference is between `mqtt` and `tcp`.  Wouldn't a "standard" MQTT connection that's not going over WebSockets be using TCP anyhow??

Comment: There is no difference between `tcp` and `mqtt` execpt some client libraries only support one. `wxs` and `alis` are specific customisations for systems run in China e.g. WeChat is `wxs` iirc